# WinRT Multicast Socket Bound To Single Adapter

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I have a datagram socket that is used to send and receive multicast packets.  When used it sends and receives data on all Adapters on the physical device.  Is there a way to specify which adapter is used instead of using them all?

If I bind with

```
await _datagramSocket.BindServiceNameAsync(ServicePort);
```

Then all adapters are used. If I bind with

```
await _datagramSocket.BindEndpointAsync(new HostName(AdapterHostname), ServicePort);
```

Then it throws the following error:
 "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072740)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally socket binds on IPADDRESS and PORT number. when you will try to bind it again using the same PORT number, it will through the error. Either you dispose the first connection (which may take a while, use some sleep between two calls), then try to bind again 
or
use different port number.

Comment: Thanks Narinder, however I'm using one or the other of the above lines of code and it's the first and only socket I'm declaring in my App. That said I would want the same port number on different IPs. Is that not possible?

Comment: Hi Oli, You cannot bind multiple end points (multiple IPs) with single socket object, make multiple socket object and use collection to maintain them (one object for each IP & PORT), When you want to send data to each end point, loop the each object and send data to each client. use collection object ` public static SortedList<string ,TcpClient> clientSocketCollection = new SortedList<string ,TcpClient>();`

Comment: Thanks Narinder, I stupidly didn't check netstat before posting. It looks like Win RT binds the port I need to all adapters by default so what I want to do is not possible.